# standard multivariate normal random vector using Boost::random

Tags: c++, boost, random, geometry, boost-random

I would like to **generate random points on a 2D surface,** distributed around a x0, y0 coordinate.

I understand that what I need to generate is called "*standard multivariate normal random vector*", but I don't know how to do it in C++, for example using the Boost::random library.

I know there is an algorith for generating this, called [Box–Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller) but I would think that this must have already been implemented properly in Boost.

Is there any simple way to generate multivariate normal distribution, using Boost::random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It seems to be](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/random/normal_distribution.hpp):

```
// deterministic Box-Muller method, uses trigonometric functions
template<class RealType = double>
class normal_distribution
{
```

But Box-Muller isn't 2D.  All you really have to do to get the 2D version is to take the two random numbers generated and add them to the `x0, y0` coordinates.

Comment: Indeed, an n-dimensional normal distribution is normal in each of its components. Write out the density function, you see that it factors as a product if 1D density functions. Also, use C++0x's `<random>` if you have it ;-)